# How many Python installations do I have?

Tags: python, visual-studio, anaconda, spyder, sql-server-2017

Some months ago I installed Python on my laptop in order to practice the language (through the textual cmd interface: >>>). A little while later I installed Anaconda & Spider in order to have a better development tool.
Meanwhile I added Python support to the Visual studio in order to try it (I use VS for C#).

Finally I installed SQL Server 2017 which full supports Python.

How many Installations of Python do I have?
Do all those tools use the same installation, or each one has its own?

As a consequence, when I install a new library using pip, will it be available to all the development tools?

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: Generally, each version installs to its own folder. You can then use explicit paths to choose which version to use (or virtual environments). Most likely one version will be the default on your path and is what will execute when you type `python` at a console/shell.  You can check which version that is using `python -V`. For ease of use, just make sure your path points to the version you want to use by default first.

Answer (score 1):

As Basic writes above, the various installations are in separate folders. Dependent on the options you chose when installing SQL Server 2017, you might have ended up with two Python installations (in addition to the ones you already have):

- In-Database - this is the one the SQL Server engines uses when you
  execute a `sp_execute_external_script`. This is normally installed
  at: `C:/path_to_sql/instance_name/PYTHON_SERVICES`.
- Standalone installation - If you want to execute standalone apps etc. 
  Normally installed at: `C:/path_to_sql/140/PYTHON_SERVICES`.

When you install a new library with `pip` it will only be available for whatever installation you target. I have written a little bit about installation of Python in SQL Server 2017 [here](http://www.nielsberglund.com/2017/04/20/sql-server-2017-python-executing-from-sql/).

Niels